# Keep same image size while zooming in/out of a website

Tags: html, css

I stubled upon this website and I would like to know how the design was made:

https://www.zoolana.io/home

There's a background image and some text in the middle, the interesting thing is that no matter how much you zoom in or out, the size of the background image stays the same, only the content changes. How can I replicate the same structure?

Comment: set `background-size` to `cover` of div having full width, height & image as background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set background-size to cover of div having full width, height & image as background.

```css
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
div{
    color:white;
    background-image:url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1644665154099-57f1f473b0cb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1469&q=80");
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover; /* This to make background image size to cover all dimension of div element.*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is testing
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is done by specifying the size of the element in units of **viewport height (vh)** and/or **viewport width (vw)**.
In the case of your example, the logo in the center is set to `width: 55vw`, meaning 55% of the viewport's width. The background image is set to `height: 100vw`, meaning 100% of the viewport's height.

Comment: Your answer isn't answering the OP's question.

Comment: He's asking about how to keep the same image size regardless of zoom. background-size: cover is irrelevant to this.

Comment: Can you add a snippet supporting your answer?